# Links on background picture

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, background

I'd like to use links on a background picture (see sample http://goo.gl/GfkD6M). How can I add links to parts (e.g. shapes) of that picture, as the texts "Link1" and "Link 2" indicate?

Comment: You can use the HTML `map` tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) or just put divs inside the container with the background image and position them accordingly ...

Comment: How does the map tag fits into the css code?<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <style>
      html {
 background: url('images/field.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

Comment: *HTML* map tag ;) so it's not in the CSS ... (I don't like w3fools, but have a look at this trivial example with clickable planets: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

Comment: Sure, but where do I have to put the reference to the map when the image is only referenced in the css?

Comment: No idea - i would prefer the other solution (correctly position transparent clickable elements above the image ...) anyway ...

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is no even not possibly to do it like this. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but there are several ways to do that indirectly :

**1.** you can use seperate the images.

**2.** put a div on the image with a lower index than the image

```
.getclick_link1 {
      /* Get the position and width of Link1 with F12 in Chrome */
      z-index : <put a z-index for the image> - 1;
      width : <the width of Link1> ;
      height : <the height of Link1>;
      position : absolute;
      left : <Get the left position of Link1 in the image>;
      top : <Get the top position of Link1 in the image>;
}
```

In JQuery do this :

```
$(function(){
    $(".getclick_link1").click(function() {
        window.location = "The address you like to redirect"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Image map doesn't work with background images. If you still want to work with background images, You may position transparent images absolutely over the background image and anchor them. Give a higher z-index to the absolutely positioned transparent image, so that it is clickable.